# How to install Windows 7 to UEFI system?

Tags: windows-7, boot, uefi

I have a new HP laptop that came with Windows 8.  I want to do a dual-boot with Windows 7.  I have Home Premium x64.  I disabled Secure Boot, and the laptop now will start to boot the Windows DVD but quickly bombs out with:

> Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be
>   the cause. To fix the problem:
>
> 1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer
> 2. Choose your language settings, and then click Next.
> 3. Click Repair your computer.
>
> If you do not have this disc, contact your system administrator or
>   computer manufacturer for assistance.
>
> File: **\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\BCD**
>
> Status: **0xc000000d**
>
> Info: **An error occurred while attempting to read the boot
>   configuration data**

Comment: You need to make sure the disk is a EFI bootable disk

Comment: Did you perhaps move the `Boot` folder instead of copying it?

Answer (score 1):

Some BIOSes are incompatible with Win7 UEFI-64.
If they have an option to enable Legacy\CSM\BIOS support then try enabling it and then UEFI-boot. Otherwise, look for a BIOS update from the manufacturer.
If a Win8 UEFI-64 Install boots but a Win7 UEFI-64 Install gives a 0xc000000d error - it is a sure sign of a BIOS issue.